# what is wrong with my code in this "Escape Sequences in Strings" challenge on FreeCodeCamp?

Tags: javascript, escaping

I can't seem to get past this challenge and it's driving me nuts. I thought I followed the instructions correctly. Can someone please figure out what the error is? (I have a feeling it's something stupidly simple.)

The challenge is here: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/escape-sequences-in-strings, below is my code.

```
var myStr =
FirstLine\n
\\SecondLine\\
\rThirdLine;
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: 1st line error: unexpected '\' and missing semicolon; 2nd line error: unexpected '\'; 3rd line error: unexpected '\'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make the challenge work, you're going to need your whole string in quotes and on one line.

So change

```
var myStr =
FirstLine\n
\\SecondLine\\
\rThirdLine;
```

to

```
var myStr = "FirstLine\n\\SecondLine\\\rThirdLine";
```

Answer (score 1):

valid 2021,2022, 202x URL link to the problem:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/escape-sequences-in-strings

freeCodeCamp asks for it as console output;

```
FirstLine
    \SecondLine
ThirdLine
```

this is the solution to the problem;

```
var myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\\SecondLine\nThirdLine";
```

1. With "\n" we move to the new line.
2. With "\t" we create a space on the new line.
3. With "\" we write the \ character on line 2.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I was able to answer the challenge and have the test cases pass:

`var myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\\SecondLine\nThirdLine"`

Answer (score 0):

var myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\SecondLine\nThirdLine";

This will work

Comment: Maybe you can explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

var myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\SecondLine\nThirdLine";

this is working.

Solution:
we use newline(\n) after FirstLine,
use tab(\t) and backslash(\) before SecondLine 
and newline(\n) after SecondLine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I passed the challenge:

```js
var myStr ="FirstLine\n\t\\SecondLine\nThirdLine"; // Change this line
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash before `Second`

Answer (score -1):

var myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\SecondLine\n\ThirdLine";

works also!

Comment: Hi, you might want to expand your answer. The OP asked "what is the error". If you're wondering why you're getting negative votes, have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

```
var myStr = "FirstLine\n\t\\SecondLine\nThirdLine";
```

This surely works and I found out why.
**=strings** must be placed in double quotes, so they may be considered as strings.